# How to use the SAX parser to read XML tags contained within other tags

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

This is my first post so if I haven't made myself clear I'll happily provide more details.
I'm writing a routing API using Java. The majority of the file is parsing correctly bar one part. The part of the XML I'm interested in looks like this:

```
<way id="30184957" user="Central America" uid="69853" visible="true" version="2" changeset="4961491" timestamp="2010-06-11T10:52:19Z">
  <nd ref="332597303"/>
  <nd ref="332597551"/>
  <nd ref="332597552"/>
  <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
  <tag k="name" v="Rae's Court"/>
</way>
</b>
```

The relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) 
{
    if (qName == "node") //if the tag value is node
    {   
        Node currentNode = new Node(0, 0, 0); //new node with all 0 values
        currentNode.nodeID = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue(0)); //set the ID to the id of the node
        currentNode.nodeLat = Double.parseDouble(attributes.getValue(1)); //set the Lat to the Lat of the node
        currentNode.nodeLong = Double.parseDouble(attributes.getValue(2)); //set the Long to the Long of the node
        allNodes.add(currentNode);
    }       

    if (qName == "way") //if tag value is way
    {
        currentWay = new Way(0, null); //create a new way with 0 values
        currentWay.wayID = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue(0)); //set the way id to the id of the way
    //  
    }

    if (qName == "nd") //if tag value is nd
    {
        Node searchNode = getNodeByID(Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue(0))); //use getNodeByID method to check if
        currentWay.containedNodes.add(searchNode);
    }
}
```

**My problem:**

I'm trying to create a way object that contains the ID and a list of nodes that it contains (the nd tag) the nd tags are just references to node objects that are successfully created earlier. Currently I am using 2 ArrayLists, one for the nodes and the other for ways. However the `getNodeByID()` method has to search through the list every time it hits an nd and is drastically slowing me down for larger XML files.

I can't seem to find a way to read the nd's in with the way, and instead have to search them in a different if statement.

Is there any way I can find a way and then in the same statement, all the nd's related to it? If so it would make creating my objects much easier as I am planning on changing those array lists to hashmaps.

Sorry if I haven't been clear...I'm not very good at describing these problems in text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing nodes to be searched in a `List`, use a `Map<Integer,Node>`.  That way searching will be O(1) instead of O(n).  If you need to have them in input order, then add them to a `List` as well for later use, but use the `Map` for searching.

Instead of

```
allNodes.add(currentNode);
```

you'd have

```
allNodes.put(currentNode.nodeId, currentNode);
```

Comment: Input order wouldn't be an issue as each node has a lat/lon attached to it and (not yet but once i have this sorted) will contain a collection of ways that it can see. SO what your suggesting would mean when i find an nd, I then look through the map as opposed to my list of nodes?

Comment: Yes, searching the map is a constant-time operation instead of depending on the length of the list.

Answer (score 0):

insert the code of `(qname=="nd")` in the endElement method and not in the startElement method.

Comment: Not to be rude, but how would this help? Do you mean an if statement?

Comment: because "nd" tag should be processed only when the handler sees the end of "way" tag.

Comment: Aha! so if I stick the nd call in end element, it will pick up the nd's within the way! Actually thinking about it, that makes perfect sense. I'll try it and get back to you...thanks!